# Connection of curvature of some curve point tangent to a circle centerd at the origin and the magnitude of the curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I can somewhat imagine the correlation between the radius of curvature and magnitude of a vector like this:

If some curve **C(s)** is tangent at point **C(p)** to a circle with radius **R** centered at the origin, then if its radius of curvature **Rc** at **p** is greater than **R**, then its magnitude should increase after **p** because the osculating circle is bigger than the one centered at the origin. If you draw the circle tangent to **C** at **C(p)** with radius **Rc** then its magnitude will also be increasing in the direction of increasing **p**. Since the osculating circle's magnitude is increasing shortly after **p**, it should be reasonable to expect **|C(p)|** to also increase after **p**.

I realize this statement is very vague so:

1. Is this true or are there counterexamples?
2. If true, how can this be proved in terms of the properties of being tangent to the circle like the derivative wrt s of the magnitude being 0 at the point of tangency?

Comment: By “increasing magnitude” you mean that the curve lies inside or outside the circle?

Comment: I meant that the magnitude |c(s)| should increase because the initial circle with radius R, being centered at the origin, marks a line where the magnitude of all vectors = R. If the curve is tangent to said circle, then |c(p)| = R. However, having a radius of curvature Rc > R, it should be tangent to some circle bigger than the former, one with radius Rc with the center somewhere opposite past the origin. I'm not allowed to post pictures, so I can't provide any diagrams for this. Sorry.

Comment: You’re not right.  It depends also on the derivative of the curvature.

Comment: Can you clarify? I have trouble seeing how the derivative of the curvature affects the change in magnitude near p since the very small neighborhood approximated near p is only dependent on |T'|.